# Resolving dependencies in global actionfilters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, action-filter

I have inherited from and extended the HandleErrorAttribute of MVC3 with some custom logging.

One thing I am struggling to do though is to neatly resolve a dependency in it using Castle Windsor.

Generally I resolve these sorts of dependencies in an extension of the ControllerActionInvoker, but it seems that the HandleErrorAttribute does not pass through here.

Where is it invoked from that I can hook in and extend it?

Thanks.

As an example of what I currently do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6627002/148998

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "generally I resolve these sorts of dependencies in an extension of the ControllerActionInvoker"? Are you talking about "InvokeActionMethodWithFilters"?

Comment: If you look at the answer on the link I included he has a class called WindsorActionInvoker. I basically do it the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was extending the ControllerActionInvoker and resolving any attribute dependencies there, specifically for the exception filters.

The code:

```
  public class WindsorActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;

        public WindsorActionInvoker(IKernel kernel)
        {
            _kernel = kernel;
        }

        protected override ExceptionContext InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList<IExceptionFilter> filters, System.Exception exception)
        {
            foreach (var actionFilter in filters.Where(actionFilter => !(actionFilter.GetType() == controllerContext.Controller.GetType())))
            {
                _kernel.InjectProperties(actionFilter);
            }

            return base.InvokeExceptionFilters(controllerContext, filters, exception);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The HandleErrorAttribute is an `IExceptionFilter` so you probably need to also override `InvokeExceptionFilters` on your ControllerFactory and inject your dependencies there.

Comment: you set me on the right path, thanks, but there is no such method to override in the ControllerFactory.