# Castle Windsor not supplying NLog component when using ASP.NET MVC filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, nlog

**Registration**

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.NLog)
                                                         .WithConfig("NLog.config"));
```

This code is as per [this documentation page](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Logging-Facility&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Now this is the code where NLog will be used i.e. Castle Windsor will supply NLog as the _logger implementation:

```
public class EmailController : Controller
{

    private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;

    ...

    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return _logger; }
        set { _logger = value; }
    }

    public ActionResult Send(UserMessageModel userMessage, bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                // Do something
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(string.Format("Error msg:{0}\rError stacktrace:{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

However if I change the code thus:

```
[CustomHandleError]
public class EmailController : Controller
{
    [CustomHandleError]
    public ActionResult Send(UserMessageModel userMessage, bool captchaValid, string captchaErrorMessage)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
public class CustomHandleError: HandleErrorAttribute
{
    private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;

    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return _logger; }
        set { _logger = value; }
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            base.OnException(null);
        }

        _logger.Error(string.Format("Error msg:{0}\rError stacktrace:{1}", filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext.Exception.StackTrace));

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the _logger is "NullLogger.Instance". I thought that the fact that I had a "Logger" property meant that Castle Windsor would then change _logger to NLog similar to the previous code.

What could I be misunderstanding?

### EDIT

I've now added the code [here](https://github.com/DavidSSL/ASP.NET-MVC-Sandbox/tree/CastleWindsorAndFilters/Version4InternetApplicationDefault) and if anyone can have a look at it that would be great.

FYI: There are 4 commits.
The first commit was the initial commit
The second commit was showing that I could get NLog to work as I required
The third commit was demonstrating that I could get the Data Attribute working i.e. I successfully registered the Filters in Castle Windsor
The last commit is the issue I described above i.e. I can't get the centralised logging to use NLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are not created automatically through the container. You need to leverage IActionInvoker into your controller factory.

Read this post
[Castle Windsor - Injecting IActionInvoker Implementation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622613/castle-windsor-injecting-iactioninvoker-implementation-issue)

**EDIT**

Your custom filter needs to derive from ActionFilterAttribute instead of HandleErrorAttribute in order to have dependencies injected by the container (leveraging on the IActionInvoker implemented in your sample). 
If the purpose of your filter is handling errors, implements IExceptionFilter as well.

Comment: I've added the code given but still the Logger is set to the NullLogger. One thing that I've noticed, which is strange, is the fact that "ActionExecutedContext" of "WindsorActionInvoker" never gets executed.

Comment: Why you added error handler attribute at class level and at method level as well? I guess actioninvoker works at class level only

Comment: I've tried putting the error handler attribute at both the class and method level and it didn't work. I'll have to put up some code on Github which might be more helpful.

Comment: Did you try to use the attribute at class level only with my IActionInvoker sample?

Comment: Yes I tried using the attribute at class level only, method level only and both levels. I'm pretty sure it's something stupid I'm doing although I can't pinpoint it at the moment.

Comment: I've added a link to the code I'm experiencing trouble with if you're still curious

Comment: Solution on the EDIT section.

Comment: That makes sense. As soon as I've got it working I'll mark this as the answer or otherwise

Comment: I modified your sample as follows:
public class CustomHandleError : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter and Logger has been injected. Do the same and LMK.